# jquery ajax post data always Null at controller side

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have been trying to make Ajax post but data always getting Null at Controller side. Pls Help:-

```
**Model:-**
public class UpdateProxyTracker
    {    
        public string Test_Reference_Id { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }        
        public string Status { get; set; }        
    }

**View:** 
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateTracker", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "optionForm" }))
{ 
<div>
        <fieldset style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
            <legend>Update Details</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test Ref Id</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="testrefId" readonly="readonly" type="text" value=@Model.Test_Reference_Id>
                    </td>
                </tr>
......
...
}

**JQuery:**
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SaveT").click(function () {

        var status = $("#statusddl").val();
        var owner = $("#owner").val();
        var remark = $("#remark").val();
        var test_Reference_Id = $("#testrefId").val();

        var data =
        {
            'Test_Reference_Id': test_Reference_Id,
            'Owner': owner,
            'Remarks': remark,
            'Status': status
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTracker", "Home")',            
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,            
            success: function (msg) {                           
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);                
            }
        });

    });
});


**Controller:**
public ActionResult UpdateTracker(UpdateProxyTracker data)
        {
                SepHomeService svc = new SepHomeService();
                bool isValid = svc.UpdateData(data);
                var result = svc.GetData();
                return View("Dataview", result);
        }
```

**Routs:**
     routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

**Question**
Here data is always Null.
I Tried passing Data as JSON.stringify(data) but did not helped
Do we need to add @Html.begin form tag to make ajax call
Data here is getting populated before ajax call but not passed to controller 
Do we need to update Route to make proper Ajax call ??
Please suggest

Comment: is your UpdateTrackr action being hit? Are you able to debug it when making the ajax call? All is setup correctly, it's really strange.

Comment: HI.. using debugger I can see action method being hit but model parameter valuse  are null.

Answer (score 6):

Try this One, It's working for me

Don't Use

```
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'json',
```

if method not a JsonResult, these things only suite  for  `JsonResult` not an `ActionResult`

Use Below Method.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {data:data},
            url: '../{ControllerName}/{MethodName}',                                                        
            success: function (response) {                           
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(errorThrown);                
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need "hijack" the form and send data using jQ AJAX. The next sample show how make this:

```
// jQ
$(function() {
   $("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue = false;

      var status = $("#statusddl").val();
      var owner = $("#owner").val();
      var remark = $("#remark").val();
      var test_Reference_Id = $("#testrefId").val();
      // ...
   });
});
```

`$('form').submit`is short-cut to handle the submit event for any form in your page.

The calls `e.preventDefault()`and `e.returnValue = false` help to prevent that form to be submitted. Only is necessary put you AJAX.

I hope this code help you

**UPDATE**
Plus the before solution, you need modify the data variable to the next code:

```
var data = {
   "data": {
      "Test_Reference_Id": test_Reference_Id,
      "Owner": owner,
      "Remarks": remark,
      "Status": status
    }
};
```

This is necessary, because you expect an argument called `data` in you controller. In addition, you attributes in JSON must use double quotes (`"`) and not single, like you use.

Comment: HI Carlos.. thanks for your advice. I tried using above code but still of no help. One thing I have noticed in source view that  Form tag is not being created for above view. Please suggest..

Comment: The OP didn't show the HTML, so we don't know if he is using `<input type="button">` or `<input type="submit">`. If it's the latter, this answer makes no sense. In fact he's not saying that the problem is that the page reloads, or that the page isn't sent by AJAX. So this answer makes no sense at all for this question.

Comment: Hi sumit kishore. You can use the next snipe: `var data =
        { "Data": {
            "Test_Reference_Id": test_Reference_Id,
            "Owner": owner,
            "Remarks": remark,
            "Status": status
        }};`. The problem is that you not include `Data` attribute, that is the variable name you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTracker", "Home")',            
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {data:data},/**important*/            
            success: function (msg) {                           
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);                
            }
      });
```

maybe need a parameter name;